# how to Populating table with data returned from 3 joins tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 4 tables

```
 1. the first table(d_cities) for cities // related with the next table  by country_id
 CityId |CountryID |RegionID |City |Latitude|Longitude      

 2. the second table(d_country) for countries 
 CountryId|Country  

 3. the third table(ip2location_db11) for ip
 ip_from|ip_to |country_code|country_name| city_name    

 4 the fourth table (ip_relation) would be like this
 CountryID |CityId|ip_from |ip_to
```

i create the fourth table to  collect custom data from the three tables and put it in one table..
this will has been done by :

join (d_country,d_cities) by id ,
then compare this names with IP table if matched
it will fetch the ids for these names & ips that matched and put it in the fourth table 
..so i write my code like this and need to support to  modify this code

```
INSERT ip_relations (CountryID, CityId,ip_from,ip_to)
SELECT *
FROM d_cities
INNER JOIN d_country ON d_cities.CountryID = d_country.CountryId
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 ON ip2location_db11.country_name = d_country.Country
AND ip2location_db11.city_name = d_cities.City
```

/// this sql statement not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO ip_relations (CityId,CountryID,ip_from,ip_to)
SELECT 
  d_cities.CityId,
  d_cities.CountryID,
  ip2location_db11.ip_from,
  ip2location_db11.ip_to
FROM d_cities
INNER JOIN d_country ON d_cities.CountryID = d_country.CountryId
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 ON ip2location_db11.country_name = d_country.Country
AND ip2location_db11.city_name = d_cities.City
```

Answer (score 1):

first, i am not sure why do you design table like this.maybe you could change them like below:

```
 d_cities: city_id | country_id | region_id  |city | latitude| longitude 
 d_country: country_id | country
 ip2location_db11: ip_from | ip_to | country_code | city_id
```

pS: I am not very sure what does country_code mean,so I keep it.base on the table structure above,it mostly like this: country to city is one-to-many and city_id must be unique, the ips is only have relation with the city_id. 
I think ,this will be a better design...

then, if you have to solve the problem based on your current tables.
you would make a unique key "UNIQUE KEY `uniq_from_to` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`) "; and,there is sql:

```
 INSERT IGNORE ip_relation  
(SELECT cA.country_id,cA.city_id,ip.ip_from,ip.ip_to FROM ip2location_db11 ip 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cy.country,ct.city,ct.country_id,ct.city_id FROM d_country cy,d_cities ct WHERE cy.country_id = ct.country_id) as cA ON ip.city_name = cA.city AND ip.country_name = cA.country);
```

this means : 1.find All city-country groups;then based on the city-country groups;2.insert into your forth table,and when ip_from-ip_to is duplicate ,will cover the data before.

hope this can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ip_relations, ip2location_db11, d_cities, d_country
set ip_relations.countryid =d_country.CountryID
, ip_relations.cityid= d_cities.CityId
, ip_relations.ip_from=ip2location_db11.ip_from
, ip_relations.ip_to=ip2location_db11.ip_to  
WHERE ip_relations.countryID=d_country.countryID and         ip_relations.cityID=d_cities.CityID and ip_relations.ip_from=ip2location_db11.ip_from
and ip_relations.ip_to=ip2location_db11.ip_to;
```

Comment: i want to update the forth table by selecting the three tables

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM d_country LEFT JOIN d_cities ON d_country.CountryId=d_cities.CountryID ' at line 7

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c87c8 : there we go, mate. Also I have edited my answer, once again ;(

Comment: no you need to join firstly to transfer data..i try it but not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming country_id, city_id, countryname etc., being same through out all three tables:

```
SELECT 
,dco.countryid AS countryid
,dci.cityid AS cityid
,ip_from
,ip_to
FROM d_country dco
INNER JOIN d_cities dci
ON dco.countryid=dci.countryid
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 ip
ON TRIM(dci.city)=TRIM(ip.city_name)
AND TRIM(dco.country)=TRIM(ip.country_name)
WHERE dco.country_id=ip.country_code

UPDATE 
ip_relation 
FROM (
SELECT 
,dco.countryid AS countryid
,dci.cityid AS cityid
,ip_from
,ip_to
FROM d_country dco
INNER JOIN d_cities dci
ON dco.countryid=dci.countryid
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 ip
ON TRIM(dci.city)=TRIM(ip.city_name)
AND TRIM(dco.country)=TRIM(ip.country_name)
WHERE dco.country_id=ip.country_code
 ) DT
 SET 
 ip_from=DT.ip_from
 ip_to=DT.ip_to
 WHERE CountryID=DT.countryid
 AND CityId=DT.cityid
```

Comment: me question is (how to update table with data returned from 3 joins tables)..so ur answer about select not update

Comment: Can you check if this is your requirement?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM ( SELECT ,dco.countryid AS countryid ,dci.cityid AS cityid ,ip_from ,' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to join is here

```
UPDATE 
    ip_relations ir 
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 idl ON ir.ip_to = idl.ip_to
INNER JOIN ip2location_db11 idr ON ir.ip_from = idr.ip_from
INNER JOIN d_cities dc ON ir.d_cities = dc.d_cities
INNER JOIN d_country dct ON ir.countryID = dct.countryID
SET 
    ir.CountryID    =   dct.CountryID,
    ir.CityId       =   dc.CityId,
    ir.ip_from      =   dcr.ip_from,
    ir.ip_to        =   dcl.ip_to
// put where condition if required
```

But when you are joining on some keys and want to update the keys i am sure all the keys will be same even after update so this will have no effect. If you update some else columns then it is practical.
To understand this assume this example.

joining two table on key which is 3. 3 is coming from 2nd table. updating column of first table with 3. So why do you need this? You need to update some else columns not the same ones you are joining.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'ir.d_cities' in 'on clause'

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'dcr.ip_from' in 'field list'